# FTP Directory browsable in Internet Explorer but not in Windows Explorer; VB.NET code to fake web browsing

Tags: vb.net, internet-explorer, ftp, windows-explorer

I have a strange case where a client's FTP server is fully browsable in a web browser, but not in a file explorer.

This is what I see in IE:
[image: ftp in IE]

And this is what I see in Windows Explorer:
[image: ftp in Windows]

What I'm really trying is to write code that reads the list of files from this ftp directory:

```
Dim ftpRequest As FtpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(ftpServer), FtpWebRequest)
ftpRequest.Credentials = New NetworkCredential(ftpServerUsername, ftpServerPassword)
ftpRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.ListDirectoryDetails

Dim ftpResponse As FtpWebResponse = CType(ftpRequest.GetResponse(), FtpWebResponse)
Dim ftpResponseStream As Stream = ftpResponse.GetResponseStream()
Dim ftpResponseStreamReader As StreamReader = New StreamReader(ftpResponseStream)

Console.WriteLine(ftpResponseStreamReader.ReadToEnd())

ftpResponseStreamReader.Close()
ftpResponseStream.Close()
ftpResponse.Close()
```

But the code fails with a 451 error:

> **The remote server returned an error: (451) Local error in processing.**
>   (Details: 451 requested action aborted: local error in processing)

---

**Questions:**

1. Why is the FTP browsable on IE but now in Windows? Should I tell my
   client to change some properties on the FTP setup to make it
   directory-browsable in Windows?
2. Is (1) necessary? Instead is it
   possible to add/change my code to imitate web-browsing so that the
   list of files can be read?

Comment: have you tried embedding the username and password in the Windows Explorer URL. i.e. "f t p : / / username : password @ IP address" (I'm having problems getting this in a comment - it is obviously without the spaces).

Comment: @Ciarán: Wow! That works! I can now see the FTP in Windows Explorer. But still doesn't work when I changed the input URL in the code to this format! :(

Comment: Glad to help, - haven't worked with ftpRequest myself so can't comment on the rest of your question. Getting a list of files from a FTP server is a fairly standard operation though so I'm sure someone else will be along to help you with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Ciarán*'s comment helped access files via Windows Explorer: the URL of the format `ftp://username:password@IPAddress/` worked.

---

For the code, however, a slash "/" at the end of the URL did the trick!

I changed the directory name from `ftp://server/directory` to `ftp://server/directory/` and BOOM! VB was  able to retrieve the list of files!

I tried the same in IE, and here's what I get:

**`ftp://193.XX.XX.XX/flog`:**
[image: ftp browsing without slash after directory name]

**`ftp://193.XX.XX.XX/flog/`: (note the "/" at the end of directory name)**
[image: ftp browsing with slash after directory name]

Anyone else stumbling here with a `(451) Local error in processing` can try this and see if it helps!

**Additional Note:**
The URL of the format `ftp://username:password@IPAddress/` (again, note the ending "/") also works in code. With this, you can skip the line `ftpRequest.Credentials = ...`.